# Css - Multi Animated Progress Bar with Different Progress Percentages

Tags: html, css, keyframe

I have an Animated Progress Bar that works fine, but I want to have more than one  with different percentages I have had a go at this with no look I have added a jsfiddle below.

**Jsfiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8sja2577/**

---

```
 <p><span class="subtitle"><h3>bar1</h3></span></p>
      <div id="progressbar"><div id="other" ><div id="pbaranim"></div></div></div>

  <p><span class="subtitle"><h3>bar2</h3></span></p>
  <div id="progressbar"><div id="progress" ><div id="pbaranim"></div></div></div>
```

---

CSS

---

```
#progressbar {
width: 100%;
height: 21px;
background-color: #ccc;
padding: 2px;
margin: .6em 0;
border: 1px #000 double;
clear: both;
border-radius:20px;
}

#progress {
border-radius:20px;
background: red; /*-- Color of the bar --*/
height: 15px;
width: 0%;
max-width: 100%;
float: left;
-webkit-animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
-moz-animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
-ms-animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
} 

#other {
border-radius:20px;
background: red; /*-- Color of the bar --*/
height: 15px;
width: 0%;
max-width: 100%;
float: left;
-webkit-animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
-moz-animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
-ms-animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
}

#pbaranim {
height: 15px;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background: url('http://www.cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/7/7uo1osj.gif') repeat-x;
-moz-opacity: 0.25;
-khtml-opacity: 0.25;
opacity: 0.25;
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=25);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=25);
filter: alpha(opacity=25);


@-webkit-keyframes other { from { } to { width: 100% }}

@-moz-keyframes other { from { } to { width: 100% }}

@-ms-keyframes other { from { } to { width: 100% }}

@keyframes other { from { } to { width: 100% }}



@-webkit-keyframes progress { from { }to { width: 36% }}

@-moz-keyframes progress { from { } to { width: 36% }}

@-ms-keyframes progress { from { } to { width: 36% }}

@keyframes progress { from { } to { width: 36% }}
```

Comment: you should change the id into classes if you would use it more than once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `other` style to use the `other` animation:

```
#other {
    border-radius:20px;
    background: red;
    height: 15px;
    width: 0%;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: left;
    -webkit-animation: other 2s 1 forwards;
    -moz-animation: other 2s 1 forwards;
    -ms-animation: other 2s 1 forwards;
    animation: other 2s 1 forwards;
}
```

[Fixed fiddle (using classes instead of ids)](https://jsfiddle.net/8sja2577/1/)

Please note that ids should be unique and `h3` cannot be a child of either a `p` or a `span`

Answer (score 0):

Id of progressbars is uniqe , you must change other progressbars id to work it successfully